# DVD writer doesn't detect, driver corrupt error

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525, and my DVD drive suddenly stopped showing in Windows Explorer. When I checked device manager it shows this error *"Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing."*

I tried to disable and re-enable it, also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the device. When it does re-install I get a prompt saying that "Windows has determined that this is the most current driver for your device."

The device shows up in device manager with a yellow exclamation mark, is there any way I can download the drivers as there is no manufacturer name on the device and I can't find drivers for the DVD drive which is named "HL-DL-ST DVD+-RW GSA-T40N" in device manager.

My current operating system is Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some searching, but I did find [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982116) that might help

In short, its a registry entry that got corrupt and needs to be deleted

Comment: I downloaded Microsoft Fix It and it run an automated troubleshooting which fixed the error. Thanks!